# How does rails handle form validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

When a rails form fails on the the front end, how is the javascript handled? e.g. a numericality error fails or a required: true option is not fulfilled.

I would like to add a callback function to this. Is there any way to execute some javascript on the failure?

Answer (score 3):

There is no javascript involved on the rendering of the errors on a rails form. The way the errors are displayed are determined by a function called `field_error_proc`, specifically `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc`. You can check Ryan Bates' [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/39-customize-field-error) about it

If you are submitting your form via AJAX, you can attach a listener for the `ajax:success` event. Otherwise the only (ugly) way I can imagine is to do something like:

`$(document).on('app:form-has-errors', function() { //do what you have to do}` and on the view

`<script>$(document).trigger('app:form-has-errors');</script>` if the object in the form has errors (`@your_object.errors.any?`).

I don't think it is possible in another way since the submit and re-render on errors are complete http requests that will clear any events you might bind to the document.

Answer (score 2):

Rails built in validation doesn't operate on the front end (client-side), it is done on the server.

If you want to do javascript validation you will need to find a gem for this or use a jQuery library, or write the validation code yourself.

The normal way form validation is done when using vanilla Rails is like this

1. The invalid form content is submitted to the controller
2. The controller uses the content to make the ActiveRecord object
3. The controller tries to save the object to the Database, kicking off a set of steps that starts with checking the object's validity
4. The model's validators say it's not valid and "decorate" the object with error messages specifying in which ways it is not valid.
5. The controller sees that the save failed and renders the view that had the original form in it, providing that view with the object, now with error messages.
6. The view when it renders the form checks the object for error messages, if it sees any it helpfully displays them to the user. It also populates the fields with the data that the user had previously entered that it gets from the object.